# Opening a file in the current directory

Tags: c++, file, directory

I'm trying to load files, and previously I was using hardcoded file locations, (like "c:\location\file.txt") but now that a few friends are also using the file, I'd like to allow them to put the executable wherever they want.

my current code looks like:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("c:\\client\\settings.cfg");
```

I'm trying to change it so that the user puts their executable into whatever folder they want, and then they create a folder and put their settings file into it and the exe will load that with their settings.

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("\\settings\\settings.cfg");
```

I have some basic error handling in place, and now the program always errors out saying that it can't find the file.

The file structure looks like this:

```
[ART]
  asset.png
[SETTINGS]
  settings.cfg
client.exe
```

This seems like a really simple thing to do, but I can't find any way to do it. Every example and tutorial about reading and writing to files deals only with files in the executable's directory, or hardcoded into c:\folder...

Could anyone point me to how I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search path for most systems starts with the current working directory and then to a `PATH` environment variable.  So, all you need to do is specify the file/folder without the absolute path markings and it will use the path relative to the working directory:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("settings\\settings.cfg");
//           ^^ Note the lack of \\ to start the file path
```

Comment: @user2827019 As I mentioned in my answer, this isn't relative to the directory of the executable. It's only relative to the user's current directory. It will only match the executable's directory if the user starts the executable from within its directory.

Comment: @user2827019:  No problem.  One thing to note is that it is based on the *working directory*, not the executable directory.  So if they create a shortcut and change the working directory (the "Start In" folder for a windows shortcut), it will attempt to look there.

Answer (score 3):

Paths beginning with `\` are always relative to the current drive's root directory. If the current drive is `C:`, then `\settings\settings.cfg` means `C:\settings\settings.cfg`.

Note that you can use `/` in order to avoid escaping everything. So you can use: `settings/settings.cfg`. This will be relative to the user's current directory. Note however, that this doesn't necessarily correspond to the directory where the executable resides. If you need the directory of the executable, then you need to use a Windows API function to get it:

```
#include <Windows.h>
// ...

HMODULE module = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameW(module, path, MAX_PATH);
```

Now if you want to open `settings/settings.cfg` relative to the directory of the executable, create a path that starts with `path` and append `/settings/settings.cfg` to it.

Comment: So there isn't a way to do it? I always have to specify the exact location for everything? If I change my code to `\settings\settings.cfg` it's always going to put and read the file in C:/settings/settings.cfg even if they "installed" to c:\game or c:\client.

Comment: @user2827019 Use the GetModuleFileNameW() function, as shown in the code.